# jQuery Tablesorter Pager- Set first displayed row

Tags: jquery, plugins, tablesorter, pager

I am using the TableSorter and Pager plugin from here:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

I want the table to display results starting at some defined index- for example, if my index is 14, I want the table to display the 'page' of results 11-20, so my row is shown, rather than starting at the default page 1, showing results 1-10.

I have this working as expected, but with some fairly ugly code..

First I work out the page that needs to be displayed (C#):

```
int index = 24;
int pageToDisplayFirst = 1;
while (true)
{
    if (index - 10 > 0)
    {
        pageToDisplayFirst++;
        index -= 10;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Then I set the page by this awful loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < <%= pageToDisplayFirst %>; i++) {
    $(".next").trigger("click");
}
```

Here is the jQuery initialisation code, nothing special:

```
 $("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({
     cssAsc: 'sortasc', cssDesc: 'sortdesc', cssHeader: 'unsorted',
     sortList: [[0,0]]
 }).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
```

So can anyone suggest a more elegant, efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know c# but you could just do this:

`pageToDisplayFirst = Math.floor(index / itemsPerPage + 1)`

```
 //found this code in the plungin source
this.defaults = {
    size: 10,
    offset: 0,
    page: 0, <<<<
    totalRows: 0,
    totalPages: 0,
    container: null,
    cssNext: '.next',
    cssPrev: '.prev',
    cssFirst: '.first',
    cssLast: '.last',
    cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
    cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
    seperator: "/",
    positionFixed: true,
    appender: this.appender
};
```

maybe you this will work

```
$("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({
    cssAsc: 'sortasc', cssDesc: 'sortdesc', cssHeader: 'unsorted',
    sortList: [[0,0]]
}).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), page: <%= pageToDisplayFirst %>});
```

Comment: I sat and stared at those default options for aaagess, why didn't 'page' click? :p
Thanks, that helps heaps!